Helmholtz decomposition of flow at non-equilibrium steady state
I'm trying to work through Karl Friston's mathematical derivation of the Free Energy Principle from Langevin Dynamics (see this paper). I'm confused about the part at the end of page 8 where he uses the Ao/Helmholtz decomposition to rewrite the flow, $f(x)$ from the Langevin equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x) + \omega$, into $f(x) = (\Gamma - Q) \nabla_x \ln(p^{\ *}(x))$ at non-equilibrium steady state (NESS). The probability density over states at NESS (i.e. NESS Density) is denoted $p^{\ *}(x)$.
What I understand so far:

The Helmholtz decomposition splits a vector field into the sum of an irrotational (curl-free) vector field $\Gamma$ and a solenoidal (divergence-free) vector field $Q$.
NESS is different from ESS because there's an arrow of time.
I get why $f(x) = (\Gamma - Q) \nabla_x \ln(p^{\ *}(x)) \implies \frac{dp^{\ *}(x)}{dt} = 0$. The explanation in Appendix 11.1 was pretty clear.

What I don't understand:

How exactly does the solenoidal flow prevent the system from "relaxing into an ESS"? The Helmholtz decomposition was supposed to answer this question, but I don't see how it does.
How do "the separable ‘dissipative’ (noise) and ‘solenoidal’ components [...] perform a gradient descent" here? I only know about gradient descent from machine learning and I assume that the term means something different in this context.

I think I'm probably missing some prerequisite concepts and/or background, so any suggestions as to where I could learn what I need to learn to understand this would be greatly appreciated.
(EDIT: Removed some sub-questions.)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I wrote up the full derivation in detail here: https://shianghuacheng.notion.site/Explaining-the-Free-Energy-Principle-to-my-past-self-118fcfd4925d8035ba35c1609bd81243.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Note that the key fact (apprently not mentioned in the Friston paper) is that  $Q$ is skew symmetric matrix. If you plug Ping Ao's decomposition into the difffusion equation you get $\partial_\mu Q_{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu p^*$ which is zero because of the antisymmetry.

Thank you, that makes sense now. Do you mind answering one of the two sub-questions I posted if you have time?

I was unfamiliar with this stuff! I have just had a pleasant morning reading some of the literature! So I am not going to much use for your other questions.
